# return exit code from ant to a batch file

Tags: java, ant, batch-file, exit-code

I have several ant tasks in my .bat file to execute.
My .bat file is like below:

> call ant -buildfile task.xml target1
>   call ant -buildfile task.xml target2

For each ant task, it will execute a java program and the program will return an exit code by using *System.exit()*.

I know the exit code can be received by using **resultproperty** in ant configuration.
How can I get the exit code in my .bat file from calling an ant task?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try something like this:

1) In your ant task.xml: make it failing if the resultproperty is not 0. To do it, you can use the [fail task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/fail.html) with

- the condition that the resultProperty is not 0
- a status code equals to the status code returned from your java program

Here is sample code:

```
<exec executable="cmd" resultproperty="javaReturnCode" ...>
    ...
</exec>

<fail message="java program execution failure" status="${javaReturnCode}">
   <condition>
      <not>
        <equals arg1="${javaReturnCode}" arg2="0"/>
      </not>
   </condition>
</fail>
```

2) In your batch file: the %errorlevel% contains the return code of the last command so something like this can work:

```
call ant -buildfile task.xml target1
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 0 GOTO javaProgramErrorHandlingTarget1
call ant -buildfile task.xml target2
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 0 GOTO javaProgramErrorHandlingTarget2
REM both ant targets exit normally so continue normal job
...
:javaProgramErrorHandlingTarget1
...
:javaProgramErrorHandlingTarget2
...
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need, thanks a lot! I'm trying this way for testing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `failonerror` attribute of the [java](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) or [exec](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) tasks.  For example:

```
<java
    classpath="..."
    classname="..."
    failonerror="true"
>
    ...
</java>
```

This will cause ant to terminate with an exit value the same as the value passed to System.exit() from the Java app.

This value can then be handled in your batch script with `ERRORLEVEL`.  For example:

```
call ant -buildfile task.xml target1
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 0 GOTO ...
call ant -buildfile task.xml target2
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 0 GOTO ...
```